# Android : HeadSetHook respond to functioning of other apps

Tags: android

Can anyone help me figuring this out i am facing a problem the headset hook button in my app respond to my app properly but it also triggers the functioning of headset hook button of other apps also(some other apps not mine).

So i want to ask if there is a way of setting priorities like i set the priority of the hook button to my app so it will only respond to my app as long as my app is running.

In my main activity :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{

    switch(event.getKeyCode())
    {

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK:  
            mystart();      

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: can you maybe show some code?

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29):

> If you handled the event, return true. If you want to allow the event to be handled by the next receiver, return false.

So instead of returning `super.onKeyDown(...)`, simply return `true`.

Note that other apps may still receive the event before yours does, and if they're handling it they *should* return `true` so yours does not receive it.